# Make 2 doLogs display on the same line

Tags: iphone, xcode, formatting, logging, code-formatting

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
[self doLog:[placemark.thoroughfare description]]; [self doLog:[placemark.locality description]];
if ([geocoder retainCount]) [geocoder release];
}
```

Displays as:

[Text on 2 lines http://cl.ly/035ae51f333a35e79342/content](http://cl.ly/035ae51f333a35e79342/content)

How can I make this work so that I can display these (thoroughfare & locality) the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self doLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", placemark.thoroughfare, placemark.locality]];
```

Comment: I get a "Reverse Geocoder error: Error Domain=MKEditorDomain Code=4 'Operation could not be completed. (MKErrorDomain error 4.)'"